# Collection set unable to contain single object , How do i resolve it ? below is my code,

Tags: java

while i am trying to add single object to hashSet , it does not accept, but when i give more then one object it will accept

the same code properly work at jvm8, but it does not work at jvm7. some one please help me to resolve this.

```
package org.student.registration.dao;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.student.jdbc.util.JDBCConnectionUtil;
import org.student.registration.to.StudentContactDetailsTO;
import org.student.registration.to.StudentDetailsTO;
import org.student.registration.to.StudentPreviousEducationDetailsTO;

/**
* @author cerdik
*/

public class AllStudentsDetailsListDAO {


private static final Logger LOGGER =     Logger.getLogger(AllStudentsDetailsListDAO.class); 

/**
 * @accessSpecifier public
 * @returnType JSONArray
 * @return studentDetails
 * @throws ClassNotFoundException
 * @throws SQLException
 * @throws IOException
 * @throws JSONException
 */
public List<StudentDetailsTO> getAllStudentsDelailsList() throws     ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, IOException, JSONException{

        try{
        LOGGER.info("getAllStudentsDelailsList Method started");
        int studentId=0;
        String retrieveQuery="SELECT "
                + "student_details_t.student_id,"
                + "student_details_t.stream_type_id,"
                + "student_details_t.first_name,"
                + "student_details_t.last_name,"
                + "student_details_t.address,"
                + "student_details_t.gender,"
                + "student_details_t.phone_no,"
                +    "student_contact_details_t.student_contact_details_id,"
                + "student_contact_details_t.contact_relation_type_id,"
                + "student_contact_details_t.name,"
                + "student_contact_details_t.address,"
                + "student_contact_details_t.phone_no,"
                + "student_previous_education_details_t.previous_education_details_id,"
                + "student_previous_education_details_t.education_type_id,"
                + "student_previous_education_details_t.institution_of_study,"
                + "student_previous_education_details_t.year_of_passing,"
                + "student_previous_education_details_t.major_paper,"
                + "student_previous_education_details_t.percentage,"
                + "student_previous_education_details_t.board_of_study,"
                + "stream_types_t.stream_type_name,"
                + "education_types_t.education_type_name,"
                + "contact_relation_type_t.contact_relation_type_name "
                + "FROM "
                + "(student_details_t INNER JOIN student_contact_details_t ON student_details_t.student_id=student_contact_details_t.student_id "
                + "INNER JOIN contact_relation_type_t ON student_contact_details_t.contact_relation_type_id=contact_relation_type_t.contact_relation_type_id "
                + "INNER JOIN student_previous_education_details_t ON student_details_t.student_id=student_previous_education_details_t.student_id "
                + "INNER JOIN education_types_t ON education_types_t.education_type_id=student_previous_education_details_t.education_type_id "
                + "INNER JOIN stream_types_t ON stream_types_t.stream_type_id=student_details_t. stream_type_id) "
                + "ORDER BY student_details_t.student_id";

        PreparedStatement prepareStatement=JDBCConnectionUtil.getConnection().prepareStatement(retrieveQuery);
        ResultSet resultSet=prepareStatement.executeQuery();
        LOGGER.info("getAllStudentsDelailsList Query is Excuted");

        List<StudentDetailsTO> allStudents=new ArrayList<StudentDetailsTO>();
        StudentDetailsTO studentsDetails=null;


        HashSet<StudentPreviousEducationDetailsTO>previousEducationDetail=null;//new HashSet<StudentPreviousEducationDetailsTO>();
        HashSet<StudentContactDetailsTO>contactDetail=null;//new HashSet<StudentContactDetailsTO>();


        while(resultSet.next()){
            if(studentsDetails==null){

                 studentsDetails=new StudentDetailsTO();

                studentsDetails.setStudentId(resultSet.getInt("student_id"));
                studentsDetails.setStudentStreamId(resultSet.getInt("stream_type_id"));
                studentsDetails.setStreamName(resultSet.getString("stream_type_name"));
                studentsDetails.setFirstName(resultSet.getString("first_name"));
                studentsDetails.setLastName(resultSet.getString("last_name"));
                studentsDetails.setAddress(resultSet.getString("address"));
                studentsDetails.setGender(resultSet.getString("gender"));
                studentsDetails.setPhoneNo(resultSet.getString("phone_no"));

                contactDetail=new HashSet<StudentContactDetailsTO>();

                StudentContactDetailsTO studentContactDetail=new StudentContactDetailsTO();
                studentContactDetail.setStudentId(resultSet.getInt("student_id"));
                studentContactDetail.setStudentContactDetailsId(resultSet.getInt("student_contact_details_id"));
                studentContactDetail.setContactTypeName(resultSet.getString("contact_relation_type_name"));
                studentContactDetail.setContactRelationTypeId(resultSet.getInt("contact_relation_type_id"));
                studentContactDetail.setName(resultSet.getString(10));
                studentContactDetail.setAddress(resultSet.getString(11));
                studentContactDetail.setPhoneNo(resultSet.getString(12));
                contactDetail.add(studentContactDetail);
                studentsDetails.setStudentContactDetails(contactDetail);



                previousEducationDetail=new HashSet<StudentPreviousEducationDetailsTO>();

                StudentPreviousEducationDetailsTO previousEducationDetails=new StudentPreviousEducationDetailsTO();
                previousEducationDetails.setStudentId(resultSet.getInt("student_id"));
                previousEducationDetails.setEducationTypeId(resultSet.getInt("education_type_id"));
                previousEducationDetails.setPreviousEducationDetailsId(resultSet.getInt("previous_education_details_id"));
                previousEducationDetails.setPreviousEducationTypeName(resultSet.getString("education_type_name"));
                previousEducationDetails.setInstitutionName(resultSet.getString("institution_of_study"));
                previousEducationDetails.setMajorSubject(resultSet.getString("major_paper"));
                previousEducationDetails.setPercentage(resultSet.getString("percentage"));
                previousEducationDetails.setBoardOfStudy(resultSet.getString("board_of_study"));
                previousEducationDetails.setYearOfPassing(resultSet.getString("year_of_passing"));
                previousEducationDetail.add(previousEducationDetails);
                studentsDetails.setStudentPreviousEducationDetails(previousEducationDetail);

                }else{

                    if(resultSet.getInt("student_id")!=studentsDetails.getStudentId()){

                        allStudents.add(studentsDetails);

                        studentsDetails=new StudentDetailsTO();

                        studentsDetails.setStudentId(resultSet.getInt("student_id"));
                        studentsDetails.setStudentStreamId(resultSet.getInt("stream_type_id"));
                        studentsDetails.setStreamName(resultSet.getString("stream_type_name"));
                        studentsDetails.setFirstName(resultSet.getString("first_name"));
                        studentsDetails.setLastName(resultSet.getString("last_name"));
                        studentsDetails.setAddress(resultSet.getString("address"));
                        studentsDetails.setGender(resultSet.getString("gender"));
                        studentsDetails.setPhoneNo(resultSet.getString("phone_no"));

                        contactDetail=new HashSet<StudentContactDetailsTO>();

                        StudentContactDetailsTO studentContactDetail=new StudentContactDetailsTO();
                        studentContactDetail.setStudentId(resultSet.getInt("student_id"));
                        studentContactDetail.setStudentContactDetailsId(resultSet.getInt("student_contact_details_id"));
                        studentContactDetail.setContactTypeName(resultSet.getString("contact_relation_type_name"));
                        studentContactDetail.setContactRelationTypeId(resultSet.getInt("contact_relation_type_id"));
                        studentContactDetail.setName(resultSet.getString(10));
                        studentContactDetail.setAddress(resultSet.getString(11));
                        studentContactDetail.setPhoneNo(resultSet.getString(12));
                        contactDetail.add(studentContactDetail);
                        studentsDetails.setStudentContactDetails(contactDetail);

                        previousEducationDetail=new HashSet<StudentPreviousEducationDetailsTO>();

                        StudentPreviousEducationDetailsTO previousEducationDetails=new StudentPreviousEducationDetailsTO();
                        previousEducationDetails.setStudentId(resultSet.getInt("student_id"));
                        previousEducationDetails.setEducationTypeId(resultSet.getInt("education_type_id"));
                        previousEducationDetails.setPreviousEducationDetailsId(resultSet.getInt("previous_education_details_id"));
                        previousEducationDetails.setPreviousEducationTypeName(resultSet.getString("education_type_name"));
                        previousEducationDetails.setInstitutionName(resultSet.getString("institution_of_study"));
                        previousEducationDetails.setMajorSubject(resultSet.getString("major_paper"));
                        previousEducationDetails.setPercentage(resultSet.getString("percentage"));
                        previousEducationDetails.setBoardOfStudy(resultSet.getString("board_of_study"));
                        previousEducationDetails.setYearOfPassing(resultSet.getString("year_of_passing"));
                        previousEducationDetail.add(previousEducationDetails);
                        studentsDetails.setStudentPreviousEducationDetails(previousEducationDetail);
                }else{
                        StudentPreviousEducationDetailsTO previousEducationDetails=new StudentPreviousEducationDetailsTO();

                        previousEducationDetails.setStudentId(resultSet.getInt("student_id"));
                        previousEducationDetails.setEducationTypeId(resultSet.getInt("education_type_id"));
enter code here

                            previousEducationDetails.setPreviousEducationDetailsId(resultSet.getInt("p    revious_education_details_id"));
                            previousEducationDetails.setPreviousEducationTypeName(resultSet.getString(    "education_type_name"));
                            previousEducationDetails.setInstitutionName(resultSet.getString("instituti    on_of_study"));
                            previousEducationDetails.setMajorSubject(resultSet.getString("major_paper"    ));
                            previousEducationDetails.setPercentage(resultSet.getString("percentage"));
                            previousEducationDetails.setBoardOfStudy(resultSet.getString("board_of_stu    dy"));
                            previousEducationDetails.setYearOfPassing(resultSet.getString("year_of_pas    sing"));
                            previousEducationDetail.add(previousEducationDetails);
                            studentsDetails.setStudentPreviousEducationDetails(previousEducationDetail    );

                    }

                        StudentContactDetailsTO studentContactDetail=new     StudentContactDetailsTO();

                        studentContactDetail.setStudentId(resultSet.getInt("student_id"));
                        studentContactDetail.setStudentContactDetailsId(resultSet.getInt("student_    contact_details_id"));
                         studentContactDetail.setContactTypeName(resultSet.getString("contact_relat    ion_type_name"));
                        studentContactDetail.setContactRelationTypeId(resultSet.getInt("contact_re    lation_type_id"));
                            studentContactDetail.setName(resultSet.getString(10));
                            studentContactDetail.setAddress(resultSet.getString(11));
                        studentContactDetail.setPhoneNo(resultSet.getString(12));
                        contactDetail.add(studentContactDetail);
                        studentsDetails.setStudentContactDetails(contactDetail);

                        }
                    }

            allStudents.add(studentsDetails);//To add last student object   into the list

    LOGGER.info("Student Details retrieved by studentId and      supply to handler successfully ");
            return allStudents;
}catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
            LOGGER.error("ERROR OCCURED : ClassNotFoundException    getAllStudentsDelailsList Method");
            throw e;
        }catch(SQLException e){
            LOGGER.error("ERROR OCCURED : SQLException     getAllStudentsDelailsList Method");
            throw e;
        }catch(IOException e){
            LOGGER.error("ERROR OCCURED : IOException     getAllStudentsDelailsList Method");
            throw e;
        }catch(Exception e){
            LOGGER.error("ERROR OCCURED : Exception         getAllStudentsDelailsList Method");
            throw e;
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Welcome! Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your code is too long.

Comment: And please [don't log-and-throw](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6639963/why-is-log-and-throw-condsidered-an-anti-pattern).

Comment: I recommend you spend some time breaking this code down into a few more methods.  It will be a lot more comprehensible and will make it easier to debug. Any time you're declaring 4 unrelated exceptions can be thrown from a single method, that's a red flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put jackson-all-1.9.0.jar you might have miss that dependency.After that code might have work perfectly.

Comment: I'm baffled as to how you could determine that was the issue based upon the question provided.

Comment: I had experienced that issue ,while i am doing project.it's my guess the person may have same problem that's it.

Comment: I'm with @aroth . Can you explain your answer please. Are you saying this is the difference between jvm 7 and 8 or are you saying that only a portion of the problem is being displayed here ? An answer based on creating hashcode and equals method for the objects being added to the hashset or on similar lines would have been less surprising. There isn't even a stacktrace in question.. so how?