# How can I get stack log while running Presto in my IDE?

Tags: logging, presto

I'm learning Presto recently, so I ran Presto in my IDE.

I want to get some stack log in order to learn more detail about Presto, but I did not find the right way to config my Presto.

I found a log config at presto-main/etc/log.properties, I tried to change the io.prestosql from DEBUG to ERROR, but still did not get the stack log.

```
 #
# WARNING
# ^^^^^^^
# This configuration file is for development only and should NOT be used
# in production. For example configuration, see the Presto documentation.
#

io.prestosql=DEBUG
com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory=WARN
com.ning.http.client=WARN
io.prestosql.server.PluginManager=DEBUG
```

Answer (score 1):

For normal cases, query exceptions are returned to end user (the caller) without being logged. We avoid log-and-rethrow for cases where query fails due to reasons under full user's control (e.g. invalid query syntax). See more at [Why is "log and throw" considered an anti-pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6639963/65458). For other cases, an exception should be logged without you changing anything in the `log.properties` provided.