# How do I throw an exception and log as info?

Tags: kotlin

Need a bit quick help with Kotlin. Here is the pseudocode: When there is a  “specialCase” error, throw the exception and Log this exception as “Info”.  This is the if statement I have. Does this look like a good approach?

```
if (error.contains (specialCase)) 
{
    throw specialCaseDoesNotExistException
}
    LOGGER.info("WriteSpecialCaseasInfoandNOTError")
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you log **before** throwing or you could combine it into a single statement using `also` ([reference](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/also.html)):

```
if (error.contains (specialCase)) {
    LOGGER.info("WriteSpecialCaseasInfoandNOTError")
    throw specialCaseDoesNotExistException
}
```

```
if (error.contains (specialCase)) {
    throw specialCaseDoesNotExistException.also {
        LOGGER.info("WriteSpecialCaseasInfoandNOTError")
    }
}
```

Comment: hey @s1m0nw1, appreciate the input. Your suggestions make sense but does either of those 2 options is tied to this --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6639963/why-is-log-and-throw-considered-an-anti-pattern/6640029#6640029